# KSP Lag when above Kerbin

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm getting some heavy lag when flying over kerbin (or on the surface) sometimes. Still have not figured out any pattern. It does not happen as soon as I move above the ocean. Changing settings.cfg has not worked and neither has changing all my settings to minimum. I have 40 parts on the plane I'm trying to fly (so its not THAT big really).

I use Ferrum, B9 and KW.

Comment: Are you only experiencing it when in the vicinity of KSC?  Do you have something big on the launch pad or a landed aircraft nearby?  Anything else within ~2.3km needs real time simulating, and since it's in the atmosphere, needs real time simulating via Ferram.

Comment: There is a slowdown in 0.23, [people believe it has something to do with the water](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/62296-Excessive-slowdowns-while-viewing-atmosphere-0-23). Turning the physics-seconds-part in the settings to 0.10 might help.

Comment: I deleted my config (after it all got messed up randomly) and now its gone (with default config). At least for the most part. I sincerely hope they focus on optimisation in the next patch. The game will be so much more fun with no lag.

Comment: I blame procedural terrain. Do you see more lag over more complicated terrain? Like, bearable over plains and problematic over mountains?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug/feature that causes excessive lag when you're close to the oceans. This is because [the oceans are actually loaded as a separate planet entity.](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/41989-An-ocean-of-lag) So the only way around this is when this bug is fixed, or you try running the game with a more powerfull computer.

Comment: or running on linux :D

Comment: The 64 bit build is still quite buggy and I couldn't get it to work with my setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms myself, and I found that by placing the camera below the rocket, looking up from the terrain, would give me normal framerates. Having terrain in view would cause slowdowns.

I went with a "don't do that" solution. I also got a new computer since then which doesn't exhibit that behavior.